What resistance is offered by an appendage on an aircraft flying at 30,000ft at 200 mph?
What formula can I use for calculating the resistance offered by an appendage above an aircraft wing? The appendage has a surface area of 10 square meters, positioned at an angle of 45 degrees. The aircraft is traveling at 200 mph, at 30,000 ft.

200 mph IAS or TAS?

If your indicated airspeed is 200 mph use:

Drag = 1/2 × Area × coefficient of drag × V$^2$

If the true airspeed is 200 mph use

Drag = 1/2 × Density × Area × coefficient of drag × V$^2$

Plug the dimensions of your shape into the drag equation.
Coefficient of drag can be estimated based on literature, or can be derived through wind tunnel tests.
